# NodeJS and npm packages

Tags: node.js, git, npm

I have several node libraries that I have created which are used as imports in my main project. These node libraries are stored on npm private modules.

My dependencies portion of package.json in my main library looks like this:

`"dependencies": {`

```
"@niveus/data": "^9.0.0",
"@niveus/mediatools": "^1.3.2",
"@niveus/emulator": "^6.4.2"
```

`}`

I have updated my 'emulator' library but I am not comfortable with `npm version major` and `npm publish` until I have successfully tested it. I created my updates on a new branch for the emulator library and attempted to modify my package.json to the following:

`"dependencies": {`

```
"@niveus/data": "^9.0.0",
"@niveus/mediatools": "^1.3.2",
"emulator": "git+ssh://niveus@github.com:niveusorg/emulator.git#updatedBranch"
```

`}`

I then deleted my node_modules folder and used the command `npm install`. This is where it confused me, the libraries downloaded fine however the 'emulator' library downloaded the correct branch in the path `node_modules/@niveus/emulator`. Which I don't mind however my project can't find the module. I tried my import statements in 2 ways:

`import Emulator from '@niveus/emulator'`

AND

`import Emulator from 'emulator'`

Both attempts resulted in

`module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module '@niveus/emulator'`

AND

`module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'emulator'`

Can anyone offer me any advice or help on this matter?

Thank you for your time